# How to determine the type of object with possible and string and numeric indices in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My function can work with array and objects. Objects have keys with string-type and array have keys with numeric-type. Also there can be object without keys.

I determine two interfaces and one type:

```
interface IObjectStringKey {
  [key: string]: any
}
interface IObjectNumberKey {
  [key: number]: any
}
// object with key-string, key-number or without key
type IObjectAnyKey = IObjectNumberKey | IObjectStringKey | {};
```

My function get argument - array of this type and I want to iterate through every key of every object.

```
function myFunction( ...sources: IObjectAnyKey[]) {
        const values = [];
for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    const source: IObjectAnyKey = sources[i];
        for (let key in source) {
            const val = source[key];
        }
    }
}
```

You can see error in playground: [typescript.org/myTask](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IObjectStringKey%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IObjectNumberKey%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20number%5D%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20object%20with%20key-string%2C%20key-number%20or%20without%20key%0D%0Atype%20IObjectAnyKey%20%3D%20IObjectNumberKey%20%7C%20IObjectStringKey%20%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction(%20...sources%3A%20IObjectAnyKey%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20values%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20sources.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20source%3A%20IObjectAnyKey%20%3D%20sources%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20key%20in%20source)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20val%20%3D%20source%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) **(you need to enable 'noImplicitAny' in Options)**

[image]

Error is "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'IObjectAnyKey' has no index signature". How can I solve this problem? I need to know how to define type with different index type. Or, maybe, there is some other solve.

Comment: hmm. I didn't see any error.

Comment: @TanDuong you need to click on 'Options' and check "noImplicitAny'

Answer (score 1):

`IObjectAnyKey` is essentially equivalent to the empty type `{}`.  The type `{}` matches pretty much every value (except for `null` and `undefined`), so the union of `{}` with anything else (except a possibly `null` or `undefined` type) is also `{}`.  TypeScript therefore doesn't know what keys are in `source` (`keyof IObjectAnyKey` is equivalent to `never`, the empty set) so it balks at indexing into it.

Your `IObjectStringKey` is only slightly narrower than `{}`.  Since TypeScript introduced [implicit index signatures](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#implicit-index-signatures), any type with known literal keys can be widened to a type with an index signature whose value type is the union of all value types.  For example:

```
const literalKeys = {a: 'hey', b: 2, c: true};
const indexSignature: {[k: string]: string | number | boolean} = literalKeys;
```

The above assignment works because `literalKeys` is compatible with the index signature.  Therefore, if you **make `myFunction()` accept an array of `IObjectStringKey`**, it shouldn't prevent you from calling it:

```
function myFunction(...sources: IObjectStringKey[]) {
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    const source = sources[i];
    for (let key in source) {
      const val = source[key]; // no error
    }
  }
}
myFunction({},{a: 'hey'},{b: 2}); // still works
```

---

If you insist on using (the relatively useless) `IObjectAnyKey`, you can always just do a type assertion to make the error go away:

```
function myFunction(...sources: IObjectAnyKey[]) {
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    const source = sources[i];
    for (let key in source) {
      const val = (source as any)[key]; // explicitly "any"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript the property key of an object is always converted to a string, so `obj[1]` is equivalent to `obj['1']` and you can only implement the first interface `IObjectStringKey`. in general, you should avoid using pseudo arrays and use real arrays if all your data is contiguous.